# Linking native library in react native?

Tags: react-native

1)What does it mean by saying native library? What sort of library ? are ones will be used as graddle dependencies ?

2)How to link these?
I was facing trouble while using `link` or `rnpm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking native library means that you are going to integrate already implemented module into your application or module which completes your react native's module functionality for eg: if you prepare a video player board with all the controls so in order to play the music you have to integrate react-native video (3rd party) because there is no inbuild lib. in react native. After integrating video lib you are good to go to play.

Steps to integrate lib(android):

1) Add package name to new packages() 
2) Add dependencies to settings.gradle file and main application's gradle i.e app/gradle file.
3) sync the projects gradle because you made changes in the gradle and it's done.

After cloning/downloading the project:

1) Go to your project's home dir using cmd.
2) run `npm install`
3) Thereafter run `rnpm link or react-native link`
4) see ios folder in your project folder and if you find any pod file then run `pod install` after navigating into ios folder in cmd.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.What about using `react-native link` ? How is it useful ?And if I downloaded a project, how can I link it ?

Comment: Using react-native link or rnpm link is similar to integrating 3rd party but automatically. Please go through the edit.

Comment: Using `react-native link` shows me `command not found`. Any  suggestions?

Comment: please check you are running the command in the project's dir or you might be running the command without running npm install.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.I managed to link the project.So all the code changes in `.java` files are visible.Do I have to do manual changes in `gradle` and `androidmanifest.xml` files?I believe Linking does not changes the permissions ?